# passport js authentication not working between node front end and backend server

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have 2 different express servers, one for front end serving react js files and another backend server.

Frontend server runs on the port:3003, backend server runs on the port:8000.

When i am firing a request from frontend server for login using Local Strategy, it returns me the user details but for further requests i have to login again.

This is not the case when i have both frontend and backend code running on in same server.

Similarly Facebook and Google Login Doesn't work.

Is it not supported to have different servers for frontend backend in passportJS?

Can some please suggest how to make it work

Comment: did you get any solution?